# Will un-rooting return stock apps

Tags: unrooting

I've recently rooted my phone - mainly to remove a bunch of the stock apps that I never use, e.g:

- Google+
- Google NewStand
- FM Radio
- Google Books

I'm wondering, can I now un-root my phone, and if so will this leave these off my device? Or will un-rooting return them back to my phone?

Comment: Our of curiosity: why do you think un-rooting would revive the dead out of their grave?

Comment: @Firelord I guess because unlocking the bootloader wiped the device, I thought the reverse might reset back to a factory reset

Comment: @Ian Factory reset doesn't actually revert your phone to the factory state. A factory reset just wipes and reformats some partitions of the phone. It doesn't install anything new.

Comment: @Ian the term "factory reset" might be a bit misleading. It just refers to the device's *configuration* (i.e. `/data`) and `/cache` – not to the "read-only" areas (`/system`) where the pre-installed apps reside. For details, see our fine [factory-reset tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/factory-reset/info).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes.**

You can unroot your phone. Use the method that GUI app (SuperSU, Superuser etc.) you use offer you to do it.

**No.**

It won't bring those apps back. Rooting is just a process of adding a binary in the `/system` partition that will let the apps approved by the GUI app execute commands as the **root user**, a user that is not an object to the standard rules other users are. This process is completely unrelated to the presence of the stock apps (assuming what you mean by it are the apps sit in `/system/app` directory of the phone) If these apps are **deleted** then the only way to get them back is to install them again. If you want them to be stock apps again you need to move them (or install them in the first place) to `/system/app` directory.

Comment: This is awesome information. So now I have a very similar question. I have an app that I want to become a system app (that is not a system app by default). Can I root, make that app a system app and then unroot?

Comment: @DustinPoissant Yes.

Comment: I tried it, it doesn't work the new system apps dont show up after unrooting.

Comment: @DustinPoissant Can you describe the process you went through with details? With information like your phone, OS version, rooting method etc.

Comment: Nexus 5x, Android 7.0, SuperSU rooting method, installed an app as a system app, confirmed it was a system app after a restart, unrooted using SuperSU's "fully unroot" button within their app. And then after the restart the system app was no longer in the app list.

Comment: Since I am yet to poke around Android M and newer I really can't tell what is wrong. But far as I know, you can't manage the '/system' partition afterwards and including Android 6.0

Comment: Its a systemless root method that modifies the bootloader to allow access to the \system. It doesn't mount system like pre Android 6 root methods.

Comment: @DustinPoissant At that point, I really can't say a lot. I haven't been checking Android and rooting methods for a while and I didn't stay up to date with them.