# Can preloaded apps be restored when Factory reset-ed

Tags: samsung, factory-reset, samsung-galaxy-note

I have deleted some preloaded apps. If I restore mobile (Factory reset)

- Will the preloaded apps be restored?
- Will my device remain rooted or will I lose root?

**Device**: Samsung Galaxy Note 1 (GT N7000)

Comment: yes I mean factory reset by restore

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will un-rooting return stock apps](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/129714/will-un-rooting-return-stock-apps)

Answer (score 5):

There are two parts to your question

1. **Factory Reset**.

a) Factory reset removes user data including apps installed by the user on phone. Since your device is rooted, you can see that everything in  `/data`
and `/data/data` will be wiped.

b) Factory reset does **not** flash stock ROM. Since you have deleted preloaded apps, they will **not** be restored. If you want them restored, you have to flash stock ROM

To understand more about factory reset, please read this

[Factory reset to restore performance? What are the disadvantages?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12802/factory-reset-to-restore-performance-what-are-the-disadvantages)

2. **Root**.  You will **not** lose root on factory reset. Your phone will remain rooted

Please read this post to understand more [Can I safely do a factory reset without losing root?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/100996/can-i-safely-do-a-factory-reset-without-losing-root)

Further, unrooting will also not being back deleted apps

Please read this [Will un-rooting return stock apps](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/129714/will-un-rooting-return-stock-apps)

---

> Additional Information on reverting to stock ROM (asked by OP in comments)

***How can I flash stock ROM?***

- **Source for downloading Stock ROM**:  [Sammobile](http://www.sammobile.com/), you have to register and download ROM specific to your model and region. You can check  here also [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device)
- **Flashing Instructions**:  Can be found on many sites. Here is one such link (also having stock ROMs) from [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1424997). You can also see "additional information" of my [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/132033/recover-android-system-with-twrp-recovery)

Comment: how can I flash stack rom????

Comment: If the answer meets your question, you can click the tick mark  next to the answer to indicate  that it is "accepted". You can learn more about [accepting an answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score -3):

Your phone will be unrooted and apps will install again.

Comment: and how can I root it again???

Comment: @AliHamzaNoon you can root it again if you know how.

Comment: A factory reset will not unroot you.